# Using timed access control in airport extreme base station

Tags: airport

I have an airport base station model A1354. I am attempting to setup MAC Timed Access so a laptop can only connect between 5:00AM and 11:00pm through the Airport Utility version 5.5.2 (552.11). My AEBS is running firmware version 7.5.2

When I try to enter the time values by double clicking over the time and entering 05:00 AM and 11:00PM the time values don't stay as soon as it looses focus. Instead they become what is in the following screenshot, and the laptop looses connectivity as soon as I update the base station. I also tried entering the values in military time with the same result.

[image: Timed Access Control Setup Window]

Here is the requested screenshot:
[image: Access Control panel]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Airport panel before you clicked on Access Control?

Comment: I'm confused, how did you add the screenshot for Bill? I mean is this his screenshot or yours?

Comment: It was actually the 'Access Control' tab I was interested in seeing and in particular, Bills settings.  Thanks anyway tho

Comment: I was able to edit the question and add the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you've altered the times, click the '+' button so a second line appears, then click 'Done'.

Comment: Beautiful!  Haha, it's funny but that's not very intuitive.  Glad that sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you typing your times in the following format:
HH:MM  ?
as in, with a space between the time and AM/PM?
I know this sounds like a stupid question, but my AEBS has done some stupid things when I tried to type it without the space (e.g. 12:43PM).