# Using timed access control in airport express

Tags: airport

Have read [Using timed access control in airport extreme base station](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/7128/9058) but the fix described has not worked.

Clicking "+" reverts the times back to the default "09:00  to  17:00"?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after changing the time fields (so the cursors jumps to the next one). It's kind of user-unfriendly, bites me a lot of times as well.